# JPA stores null value in CLOB when setting an empty String

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, clob

Let's say I have an entity Entry with a Clob column like:

```
 @Entity
 public class Entry {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQUENCE_GENERATOR")
  private Long id;

  @Lob
  @Column(name = "value")
  private String data;
...
```

And in database we have an existing Entry row where VALUE is a clob initialized with Oracle's EMPTY_CLOB() function.
I need to clone the existing to a new entity, but after querying and setting an empty String for simulate the EMPTY_CLOB() from Java side, Oracle's show up a (null) value instead of an empty Clob.
Whe use hibernate as JPA implementation.

Expected after saving entity 2 with JPA:

```
SELECT * FROM ENTRY
ID VALUE
1          <------------ Returning an empty CLOB here
2 (null)
```

Actual behaviour

```
SELECT * FROM ENTRY
ID VALUE
1          <------------ Returning an empty CLOB here
2          <------------ Returning an empty CLOB here
```

Comment: Sorry there's an error in the post, the desired behaviour is:

SELECT * FROM ENTRY
ID VALUE
1          <------------ Returning an empty CLOB here
2          <------------ Returning an empty CLOB here

Answer (score 0):

It's because an empty string in Java is not NULL, and then the ORM generates an INSERT with "" for that column and the DEFAULT defined in the DDL is not applied, and eventually the '' is converted to NULL before caste-ed to CLOB.

With Hibernate, you may try to put @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true) or @DynamicInsert on the entity and don't set the column to empty string: if NULL, dynamic insert should skip it when generating the INSERT statement, so the DEFAULT defined in the DLL should be applied.
(Be aware of https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7074)
(And you may also need dyanmicUpdate = true)